# Differential pair routing for audio near RF

Tags: pcb-design, rf, differential, layout

I am routing this circuit which includes a Microphone, an amplifier and a speaker all connected to a SIM with 4G, GPS and BT antennas.
This is a small PCB and i am restrained by the space.
Can you check if my Differential routing is acceptable and if this placement will affect the RF signals or vice versa.
Thank you!

FYI:[image]
This is a 4 layers PCB
Trace width 8 mils
Trace spacing 8 mils
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are both of your inner planes ground?

Comment: 3V3 and GND, Thank you

Comment: What is the justification for audio signal differential routing to have matched trace lengths?

Comment: I know mismatched audio traces won't affect the signal but i thought it will be better. Does the resistors on the traces affect the signals? like r10 and r13?

Comment: I don't know if the traces impedance is correct here

Comment: If you care about SI and EMI, your goal should be low impedance return current paths. Signal-ground-power-signal is not a great stackup for that. Unless your parts need tens of amps I'd recommend routing power on one of the outer layers and having the two inner planes be grounds.

Comment: If you've got a spare hour, I recommend watching Rick Hartley's talk on PCB stackup: https://www.altium.com/live-conference/altiumlive-2018-annual-pcb-design-summit/sessions/extreme-importance-pc-board-stack-up - it's an extraordinarily good talk that fundamentally changed the way I think about electrical energy on a PCB. Well worth the time, and it's quite relevant to the issues you're talking about here. He also has a follow-up talk on myths about diffpairs that might help you here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG0Apol-oj0

Comment: I will watch it, thank you